# Accessing Joomla Shopping Cart (VirtueMart) Information from Cocoa / iOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, web-services, ios, joomla

I am trying to build an iOS interface for a Web Store which is built using Joomla and Virtuemart Extension. I need to access the purchased products and order ids.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,
just wondering if you worked this out? I'm looking for something similar. How to authenticate a user in iOS against a joomla database and then show content from the site. Thanks,
Rebecca

Comment: Nope still looking for it. My current solution is to load the authentication page in the WebView and load the login screen there. Let the users authenticate at the webview and parse the HTML data from there. If you are doing anything let me know.

Answer (score -2):

We only offer this as part of a complete solution, if its any useful to you : https://bitly.com/xappstudio

What payment options you would need for that btw?

Comment: don't try to sell things here try to answer the question more technical